# Windows DST endDate is about a month wrong in the years before 1996

Tags: c#, .net, date

I am having a problem with historic dates and the DST ending date in .NET/Windows.

We have inherited a database with local DateTime values.

This should not be a problem since they can be serialized on the way out, to utc with timezone (and DST) information.

But when dealing with dates before 1996 Windows insists that DST ends at the end of October, where most of the rest of the world agrees that DST ends at the end of September.

I have written a little routine to show DST end dates for windows, witch differs from Wikipedia, timeandDate.com, and other sources.

```
    for (int i = 1990; i <= 1998; i++)
{
    bool done = false;
    for (int d = 1; d <= 31; d++)
    {
        if (!DateTime.Parse($"{i}-10-{d}").IsDaylightSavingTime() && !done)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"{i}-10-{d - 1}");
            done = true;
        }
    }
}

Console.WriteLine(TimeZoneInfo.Local);
```

With the following result:

1990-10-29

1991-10-28

1992-10-26

1994-10-31

1995-10-30

1996-10-28

1997-10-27

1998-10-26

TimeZoneInfo: (UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris

BaseUtcOffset: 01:00:00

DaylightName: Romance Standard Time

DisplayName: (UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris

Id: Romance Standard Time

StandardName: Romance Standard Time

SupportsDaylightSavingTime: True

In the console (chrome/js) I have done similar:

```
for (var i = 1990; i <= 1998; i++)
{
    var done = false;
    for (var d = 1; d <= 31; d++)
    {
        if (new Date(i + "-09-" + d).getTimezoneOffset() > -120 && !done)
        {
            console.log(i + "-09-" + d);
            done = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Giving what I believe is true:
1990-09-31

1991-09-30

1992-09-28

1993-09-27

1994-09-26

1995-09-25

I have found nothing helpful yet. So I hope someone can give clue.

The obvious alternative: transform all dates to UTC, is not feasible.

Best regards.

Comment: "The obvious alternative: transform all dates to UTC, is not feasible."   Then you are doomed to forever caretake over these flimsy strings that claim to be data :)

Comment: If you are absolutely convinced that you are right, then this is a bug.  Open a support case with Microsoft and see if it gets into the bug-fix queue.  Don't hold your breath though - even though Microsoft spends a lot of effort on keeping time-zone information up to date, I'm not sure how they'd prioritize an issue that affects things 22 years ago.

Comment: Just running a quick test, the `TimeZoneInfo` object for the `Romance` time zone only has one time adjustment (at least on my system - Win 10, latest .Net) and I know this can be system dependent.  Don't know if it is possible for you, but have you considered [NodaTime](https://nodatime.org/). I ran a quick test and it seems to correctly handle the different DST values.

Comment: @Davesoft, I was waiting for something like that ;-)

Comment: @FlyDog57, People older than 22 all have birthdays, wich is how we discovered the bug. I'll file the bug and hope they fix it someday

Comment: @pstrjds, NodaTime is seriously under consideration now. Thanks.

Comment: I think that might be your best option. I doubt you would see a fix to DateTime anytime soon, especially when looking at some of the docs it seems to suggest that there are known problems/deficiencies and that is just the way it is.  Another alternative (in my opinion not necessarily a good one) is to create your own [custom time zone](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timezoneinfo.adjustmentrule.createadjustmentrule%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). You could make it match your current local, but you would be able to add your own adjustment rules to it.