# Daylight saving time before 1996 - unexpected result

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, utc

I'm living in Belgium and according to this website (https://www.astro.oma.be/GENERAL/INFO/fri001a.html), the daylight saving time changes on September 30, 1990 at 1:00 UTC.
At that moment, we should add only 1 hour to UTC time to get local time.
The days before, we had to add 2 hours.

**C# code** (https://dotnetfiddle.net/5tSNyG)

```
using System;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        DateTime myUTCDate1, myUTCDate2, myUTCDate3, myUTCDate4;
        TimeZoneInfo tzLocal = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("Romance Standard Time");
        TimeZoneInfo tzUTC = TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("UTC");

        try {
            myUTCDate1 = new DateTime(1990, 09, 30, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            myUTCDate2 = new DateTime(1990, 09, 30, 1, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            myUTCDate3 = new DateTime(1990, 10, 28, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            myUTCDate4 = new DateTime(1990, 10, 28, 1, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);
            Console.WriteLine("tzLocal.Id: {0}\ntzLocal.DisplayName: {1}\n", tzLocal.Id, tzLocal.DisplayName);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}) -> {2} ({3})", myUTCDate1, tzUTC.Id, TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(myUTCDate1, tzUTC, tzLocal), tzLocal.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}) -> {2} ({3})", myUTCDate2, tzUTC.Id, TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(myUTCDate2, tzUTC, tzLocal), tzLocal.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}) -> {2} ({3})", myUTCDate3, tzUTC.Id, TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(myUTCDate3, tzUTC, tzLocal), tzLocal.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("{0} ({1}) -> {2} ({3})", myUTCDate4, tzUTC.Id, TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(myUTCDate4, tzUTC, tzLocal), tzLocal.Id);
        }
        catch (FormatException) {
            Console.WriteLine("Invalid format.");
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

**C# output**

> tzLocal.Id: Romance Standard Time
>   tzLocal.DisplayName: (UTC+01:00) Brussels, Copenhagen, Madrid, Paris
>   9/30/1990 12:00:00 AM (UTC) -> 9/30/1990 2:00:00 AM (Romance Standard Time) //2 hours added: OK
>   9/30/1990 1:00:00 AM (UTC) -> 9/30/1990 3:00:00 AM (Romance Standard Time) //2 hours added: NOK (should be 1 added hour)
>   10/28/1990 12:00:00 AM (UTC) -> 10/28/1990 2:00:00 AM (Romance Standard Time) //2 hours added: NOK (should be 1 added hour)
>   10/28/1990 1:00:00 AM (UTC) -> 10/28/1990 2:00:00 AM (Romance Standard Time) //1 hour added: OK

I don't understand why the daylight saving time only changes on 10/28/1990 1:00:00 AM UTC.
I did the same exercice in Oracle and Java, and the results correspond to what I'm expecting (the daylight saving time changes on 9/30/1990 1:00:00 AM UTC).
I'm not a .net expert, and can't explain the difference between .net and Java/Oracle. Did I miss something ?

But on this other website (http://www.cedra.net/ENS/heuredete.html), I can read:

> 1996 : ATTENTION, changement par rapport aux années précédentes. Le retour à l'heure d'hiver se fait fin octobre, et non pas fin septembre comme avant.

If I translate to English, it says that from 1996 the daylight saving time occurs at the end of October, and not at the end of September as during previous years.
Is it possible that .net does not care about this rule ?

**Oracle query**

```
SELECT 
SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP('1990-09-30T01:00:00.0', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF') AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)) AS D1,
SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(CAST(TO_TIMESTAMP('1990-09-30T02:00:00.0', 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF') AS TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE)) AS D2
FROM DUAL;
```

**Oracle output**

> D1 : 1990-09-29 23:00:00 //2 hours subtracted: OK
>   D2 : 1990-09-30 01:00:00 //1 hour subtracted: OK

**Java code**

```
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        DateFormat dateFormatLocal = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        dateFormatLocal.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Brussels"));
        DateFormat dateFormatUTC = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS");
        dateFormatUTC.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        String[] dateStrArray = {"1990-09-30T01:00:00.000", "1990-09-30T02:00:00.000"};
        Date date = null;

        for (String dateStr : dateStrArray) { 
            try {
                date = dateFormatLocal.parse(dateStr);
                System.out.println(date + " (local) -> " + dateFormatUTC.format(date) + " (UTC)");
             } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
       }
    }
}
```

**Java output**

> Sun Sep 30 01:00:00 CEST 1990 (local) -> 1990-09-29T23:00:00.000 (UTC) //2 hours subtracted: OK
>   Sun Sep 30 02:00:00 CET 1990 (local) -> 1990-09-30T01:00:00.000 (UTC) //1 hour subtracted: OK

Comment: [Does .NET have the history of time zone changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156260/does-net-have-the-history-of-time-zone-changes)

Comment: See:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51268350/windows-dst-enddate-is-about-a-month-wrong-in-the-years-before-1996